# Remove 'New' button from 'Recently Viewed' search layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-experience

How can I remove 'New' button from the 'Recently Viewed' search layout?

[image]

Comment: pls post a picture for better understanding

Comment: Where you like to have new button?

Comment: @SantanuBoral added screenshot. this is opportunity tab. I have already removed new button from the list view.

Comment: Why don't you want that button there? If you are trying to prevent a group of users from being able to create a certain object, you would be better off controlling that through object level permissions on the users' profile.

Comment: @martin Users shouldn't be able to create new Opportunities directly. It's done in a custom page.

Comment: Then you can replace your new and edit page so no matter how user click on new button it will always redirect to your custom VF page.

Comment: You can not remove this until and unless you remove the permission to "Create" from that user OR override this page.

Comment: @ChamingaD consider accepting the latest answer which has updated information that this is now possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in a way that works across desktop and Salesforce1. On desktop, you can redirect the user to a visualforce page and block them. However, this redirect does not work on Salesforce1.

Comment: This is no longer true. You can now remove the "New" button through the list view layout as the other, more recent answer mentions. [Summer '21](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_mru_list_actions.htm&type=5&release=232)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the "New" button from listview. Please follow the steps below:

**In Lightning Experience**

1. Goto setup
2. Goto the desired object from the object manager tab
3. Click on "Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic"
4. Edit the listview

[image]

5. Remove the check from "New"

[image]

6. Press "Save" and new button should be removed from listviews.

Answer (score 0):

Tried workaround to restrict the new record creation from the recently viewed list view

​​​​​​​
**component code**

```
<aura:component  implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">

    <div class="slds-modal__container">

        <header style="position:relative">

            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"

                                  onclick="{! C.closeModel }"

                                  alternativeText="close"

                                  variant="bare-inverse"

                                  class="slds-modal__close"/>

        </header>

         <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">

            <div class="slds-p-around_medium slds-p-left_large">

                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="color:red">

                    <h2><b>You cannot create new record here.</b></h2>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</section>



 <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>

</aura:component>
```

**JS code**

```
({

    closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {

        var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToList");

        navEvent.setParams({

            "listViewName": null,

            "scope": "Options__c"

        });

        navEvent.fire();

    },

})
```

once you create this lightning component, map it to the New button in the setup > object manager

Find more details in this link

https://www.codekiat.com/2020/12/disable-new-button-from-recently-viewed-list-view-salesforce.html