# Remove Change Status button on the Lightning Lead 'Recently Viewed' List

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

Is there any way to remove this button from the page?

[image]

I've seen from this similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156006/remove-new-button-from-recently-viewed-search-layout)  that you can potentially limit by permission, but if that's not possible, is there a programmatic solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually applied a custom validation rule on the Lead to control the values that can be used by the user dependent on their profile. There doesn't seem to be a proper LEX programmatic solution and so we have to wait for Salesforce to open up configuration options on the page.